# Start interactive SSH session from Python script

Tags: python, ssh

I'd like to start an interactive SSH terminal from a Python script **without** using modules like pexpect or paramiko - I want to stick with what CentOS pre-installed Python provides me (to ease compatibility and deployment issues).

I can run commands fine using the subprocess module, but cannot get an interactive terminal.  In Perl, I would just use backticks to achieve this, but am looking for the pythonic way of doing this.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

*UPDATE* - based on @leoluk's answer, I used the instructions from [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system) to come up with: `subprocess.call("ssh ...", shell=True)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I get an interactive terminal if I use `os.system('ssh [...]')`

Comment: Using the instructions to convert os.system to Popen, I was able to make it work.

Comment: @sholsapp Can you please share your solution using Popen? Thank you!

Comment: @mart1n I've updated the question to use the code that I came up with based on the https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system instructions for replacing `os.system`.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity and simplicity for future visitors of this thread, here is an example using the OP's `subproccess.popen()` solution.

```
try:
     print("Starting SSH connection...")
     ssh_cmd = 'ssh -vvv -i your_ssh_key -o BatchMode=yes -p 22 user@server_address 2> ssh-error.log'
     subprocess.run(ssh_cmd, shell=True)

except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
     raise SystemExit(e)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use pexpext if you want to mix interaction with automatic response

http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect

Comment: The OP did say s/he didn't want to use pexpect!